# Facebook Share Button Intermittently working

Tags: .net, facebook, button, model-view-controller, share

Hi I have followed the facebook dev by entering my url and using the 'Get Code' button:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share-button/

However, the Share button only shows up intermittently. Sometimes it doesen't show up at all. I am not sure why as there are no errors.

[image]
[image]

Has anyone else experienced this?

I am using .NET MVC

EDIT: The problem only seems to occur on Chrome and not IE or Edge.

EDIT 2: This is the content of the button element when hovering over (maybe override some css width height?):

```
<body dir="ltr" class="plugin chrome webkit win x1 Locale_en_GB">
<div class="_li">
    <div class="pluginSkinLight pluginFontHelvetica">
        <div>
             <div class="inlineBlock" id="u_0_0"><a class="_2vmz" href="/sharer/sharer.php?kid_directed_site=0&amp;sdk=joey&amp;u=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.timeform.com%2Fgrand-national%2Frunners&amp;display=popup&amp;ref=plugin&amp;src=share_button" target="_blank" id="u_0_1">
                <div>
                     <button type="submit" class="inlineBlock _2tga _89n_ _8j9v">
                        <span class="_8f1i"></span>
                           <div class="">
                              <span class="_3jn- inlineBlock _2v7"><span class="_3jn_">                                                   
                             </span>
                                  <span class="_49vg _8a19"><img class="img" style="vertical-align:middle" src="https://static.xx.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v3/yr/r/zSKZHMh8mXU.png" alt="" width="12" height="12"></span></span>
                                     <span class="_49vh_2pi7">Share</span>
                                        <span class="_5n6h _2pih" id="u_0_3">4.8K</span>
                      </button>
              </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What happens when you check the DOM, is the iframe there? These social plugins sometimes have issues where they can’t figure out their size correctly, so the iframe stays at 0px height … If having the share _counter_ value shown is not a thing you absolutely need, then I would go with Share dialog, and its URL redirect version. Then you can use your own link or button, and don’t need to embed their SDK any more (which adds to the loading time of the page, and could be considered a privacy issue) - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog#redirect

Comment: How are you using the share button? Do you have a link to the page that has a problem? It is impossible to answer your question without more info.

Comment: @04FS I have added the 'contents' of the button when it is displayed. Doesen't seem to include any iFrame? Maybe oververide the CSS width and height but I'm not sure what class to ovveride.